# How to best forecast simple binary data?

Tags: time-series, beginner, categorical-data, forecast

I have a set of timeseries binary (boolean) data, with intervals of 1 day. Each day can either be 1 or 0 (true/false). What is the best way to forecast the next day/week's data based on the data I already have?

Comment: Do you just have the historic 1s and 0s? Or is there other information available?

Comment: I have the historic 1s and 0s yes.

Comment: I also have their associated dates.

Comment: @Jan van der Vegt Any insight?

Comment: Are these things more/less likely to happen on weekend days? Or when the weather is hot? Are they getting more frequent or rarer? Do they happen in clusters or independent? These are all questions you need to ask of the data and of experts who know about the data before you can think about formulating a predictive model.

Comment: One approach which might help you search the literature for methods would be to consider the binary outcomes as single samples from a latent (ie unobserved), continuously-valued on (0,1), time series process, such as an autoregressive process. What you've then got is a doubly-stochastic process. Ooh look they figured this out in 1982: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2287312?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: What all features do you have?

Comment: You can use MLforecast package. https://github.com/Akai01/MLforecast

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously consider using the bsts package (in R), with 'logistic' as the model family.  That will give you a forecast of the probability of 1's and 0's, based on past trends or periodicities (depending on how you construct the model). You can also add covariates, i.e. other things that change in a way related to your 1/0 observations, to act as predictors.

See Figures 9 and 10 on this page:

http://www.unofficialgoogledatascience.com/2017/07/fitting-bayesian-structural-time-series.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Do some feature engineering. As they told you in the comments, try
   to see if the event is more likely to happen during weekends or
   weekdays, during certain months, during a certain season or quarter,
   etc. To read some more on this topic.

   https://machinelearningmastery.com/discover-feature-engineering-how-to-engineer-features-and-how-to-get-good-at-it/
2. Explore different machine learning models. I suggest to start with a Random Forest.
3. Check your model accuracy (confusion matrix).
4. Iterate. Try other features, other models...

Just to get you up and running, you can take a look at the Titanic dataset in Kaggle. It will help you understand a bit more of the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use categorical HMM (Hidden Markov Model) or LSTM (Long Short Term Memory) networks to predict the next values of time series.